# Maven: How To Keep A Dependency Out?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jstl

I'm new to Maven.   I recently learned it to solve some dependency issues I'm having with a Java and Spring WebApp.   I've been trying maven out on a small sample webapp.   The webapp uses JSTL tags.  I found it necessary to put these tags in pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

These get 2 jars that I need:

```
jstl-api-1.2-rev-1.jar
jstl-impl-1.2.jar
```

BUT it also includes THIS jar in my WEB-INF/lib, the inclusion of which causes all sorts of errors when I try to run it in Tomcat 7:

```
jsp-api-2.1.jar
```

Is there a way I can rewrite my dependency tags to leave jsp-api-2.1.jar out of my WEB-INF/lib ?

Thanks

---

Fixed.  Thanks Guys.  FWIW, this is how I changed the dependency tags for the JSTL to not put the JSP-API jar in my WEB-INF lib:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I was able to find the groupID and artifactID at this site
https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have exclusions section, similar to the one below.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

In your case, one (or both) of the dependencies you add include the one that you do not need. Find which one, and add the exclusion section.

Comment: Virtually Real, thanks for the tip about both dependencies possibly pulling in that other jar.  Both did.  Luckily I found this great site where you can look up Maven informaiton for making dependency tags: https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#welcome

Answer (score 1):

Change the scope to 'provided'.  EG:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The provided scope ensures that jar is available to the compiler, but assumes that it will be 'provided' at runtime when the code is run.  In your cast, it is provided by Tomcat.

Comment: Perhaps in this case it would be better to have javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api at 'provided' scope? Seems this artifact is the actual implementation.

Comment: Roy, that isn't the jar I am trying to avoid.  I need the one you mentioned in my WEB-INF/lib